# Im trying to Solve a problem which basically pulls data from xml and displays in html page I am not able to populate data in table from xml file

Tags: html, css, xml, validation, xslt

I'm not sure why its not pulling the data from xml file can anyone please help me understand where the flaw is in the stylesheet so that data can be displayed in browser from xml any help would be really appreciated I've attached what I tried but doesn't seem to work. I'm pretty new to this.

1.Go to the hbemployees.xsl file in your editor. Directly after the opening stylesheet element, create the departments key, matching the employee element and using the department element for the key index. The purpose of this key will be to group the employees by department.

2.Directly after the h1 Employee Report heading, insert a for-each element that that uses Muenchian grouping to select each unique department by using the location path: “//employee[generate-id()=generate-id(key(‘departments’, department)[1])]” then sort the results by department.

3.Each time through the for-each loop, write the following HTML code to the result document:

```html
<table class="employeeList"> <caption>department</caption> <thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Salary</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Marital Status</th>
<th>Work Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

4.Within the tbody element of the HTML code you just wrote, apply a template using the departments key with the current value of the department element in order to display information on each employee within the currently displayed department. Sort the applied template by descending order of the salary element.

5. Directly after the root template, insert a new template matching the employee element. The purpose of this template will be to write a table row containing information on a selected employee.
   6.Have the template write the following HTML code to the result document:

   ```html
   <tr>
   <td>name</td> 
   <td>position</td> 
   <td>salary</td> 
   <td>phone</td>
   <td>gender</td>
   <td>marital status</td>
   <td>working status</td>
   </tr>
   ```

   where name, position, salary, phone, gender, marital status, and working status are the values of the name, position, salary, phone, gender, martialStatus, and workingStatus elements. Format salary so that it is displayed as currency.

The below is my html,css,xml code this is just displaying the header and not populating the data from xml

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl :key name="departments" match="employee" use="department" />
   <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Employee Report</title>
            <link href="hbstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         </head>
      <body>
         <header>
            <img src=" hblogo.png" alt="Harris and Barnes" />
         </header>
         <xsl:for-each select="//employee[generate-id()=generate-id(key('departments', department)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="department" />
            <departments department="{department}">
               <Summary>
                   <Name>
                       <xsl:value-of select="count(key('departments', department))" />
                   </Name>
               </Summary>
               <Orders>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('CustomerList', CustomerID)" />
               </Orders>
            </departments>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <table class="employeeList">
            <caption>
               <xsl:value-of select="department" />
         
            </caption>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th> Name </th>
                  <th> Position </th>
                  <th> Salary </th>
                  <th> Phone </th>
                  <th>Gender </th>
                  <th> Marital Status </th>
                  <th> Work Status </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="key('departments', department)">
                  <xsl:sort select="salary" order="descending"/>
               </xsl:apply-templates>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </body>

      </html>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="employee">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="position"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(salary,'$#,##0')"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="phone"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="gender"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="MaritalStatus"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl: value-of select="workingStatus"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl: template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml file to pull data and populate in html web page.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hbemployees.xsl" ?>

<employees xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <employee empID="4">
      <name>Heffner, Marian</name>
      <position>Chief Operating Officer</position>
      <phone>x10962</phone>
      <email>mheffner50@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Management</department>
      <salary>262000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="192">
      <name>Murff, Nicolle</name>
      <position>Mgr Software Client Supp</position>
      <phone>x32524</phone>
      <email>nmurff63@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Sales</department>
      <salary>137000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="295">
      <name>Vecchio, Art</name>
      <position>Line Worker</position>
      <phone>x12125</phone>
      <email>avecchio55@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Management</department>
      <salary>83000</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Part Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="294">
      <name>Lewis, Richard</name>
      <position>Met Read/Coll</position>
      <phone>x22131</phone>
      <email>rlewis19@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Production</department>
      <salary>74500</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="193">
      <name>Fleming, Angela</name>
      <position>Inventory Ck</position>
      <phone>x31751</phone>
      <email>afleming30@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Sales</department>
      <salary>99000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
</employees>
```

css file:

```html
/* Default styles */

* {
   margin: 0px;
}

header, section, article {
   display: block;
}



/* Body styles */
body {
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
   background-color: #fcdeef;
}

div#wrap {
   background-color: white;
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 1200px;
   border-left: 2px solid rgb(151, 151, 151);
   border-right: 2px solid rgb(151, 151, 151);

   box-shadow: rgb(51, 51, 51) 10px 0px 30px,
               rgb(51, 51, 51) -10px 0px 30px;
   padding-bottom: 50px;
}


div#wrap >  h1 {
   font-size: 2.9em;
   letter-spacing: 0.12em;
   font-weight: normal;
   color: #f266b5;
   text-shadow: black 1px 1px 2px;
   padding: 15px 0px;  
   font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
   text-align: left;
   margin-left: 100px;
}



div#wrap > h2 {
   margin: 25px 0px 5px 100px;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 1.9em;
   letter-spacing: 0.08em;
   font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
   text-align: left;
}



table.employeeList {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   margin: 5px 170px 30px 170px;
   border: 2px solid #c3b451;
}

table.employeeList caption {
   caption-side: top;
   text-align: right;
   font-size: 1.7em;
   color: #035aae;
   letter-spacing: 0.07em;
}

table.employeeList th {
   font-size: 0.8em;
   text-align: left;
   background-color: #035aae;
   color: white;
   border: 1px solid rgb(91, 91, 91);
   font-weight: normal;
   vertical-align: top;
   padding: 3px;
   width: 100px;
}

table.employeeList tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) td {
   background-color: #fdedf6;
}

table.employeeList tbody tr td:nth-of-type(3){
   text-align: right;
   width: 75px;
}

table.employeeList tbody tr td:nth-of-type(4){
   text-align: center;
   width: 50px;
}

table.employeeList tbody tr td:nth-of-type(5){
   text-align: center;
   width: 60px;
}

table.employeeList tbody tr td:nth-of-type(6){
   text-align: center;
   width: 60px;
}

table.employeeList tbody tr td:nth-of-type(7){
   text-align: center;
   width: 60px;
}


table.employeeList td {
   font-size: 0.8em;
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: top;
   border: 1px solid rgb(91, 91, 91);
   padding: 3px;
   width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Your stylesheet has several syntax errors. Use a tool that can point them out and allow you to fix them - e.g. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MXNWN1

Comment: After resolving my syntax mistakes it worked thanks! @michael.hor257k